# Firebase functions setting custom claims

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a problem with the function(I suspect) in which I add custom claims. Here is the code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data)=> {
  //get user and add custom claim (admin)
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
      admin: true
    });
  }).then( () => {
    return {
      message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made an admin`,
    }
  })
})
```

I call the function using the following code(I use Redux and React):

```
let addAdminRole = window.firebaseFunctions.httpsCallable('addAdminRole');

addAdminRole({email:employee.email}).then(res => {
          console.log(res)
    })
```

I get the expected message({message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made an admin`}), but the claim isn't added.

I make a separate Firebase Auth REST API via axios for authentication, but the claim 'admin' isn't there.

I have a Spark(free) billing plan and when checking the logs from firebase functions I see 'Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions' when addAdminRole is executed.

From what I read this is a message that you always get on the free plan and there shouldn't be a problem when accessing internal(google) info.

Here is the code for the axios Request:

```
axios({
      method:'post',
      url:urlAuth,
      data:{
        email:employee.email,
        password:employee.password,
        returnSecureToken: true
      }
    }).then(res => {
      delete employee.password;
      console.log(res)
      const expirationDate = new Date().getTime() + res.data.expiresIn * 1000;
      localStorage.setItem('token',res.data.idToken);
      localStorage.setItem('expirationDate',expirationDate);
      localStorage.setItem('userId', res.data.localId);
      localStorage.setItem('admin', res.data.admin)

      dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(res.data.expiresIn));

      if(logIn){
        dispatch(endAuth(res.data.idToken,res.data.localId,res.data.admin));
      }else{
        employee.userId = res.data.localId;
        dispatch(addEmplRegister(employee,res.data.idToken,admin));
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch(errorAuth(err.message))
    })
```

FOUND OUT THE ISSUE, the information about claims isn't transmitted when using REST API authentication

Answer (score 0):

Setting a custom claim doesn't take effect immediately for users with existing JWT tokens.  Those users will have to either:

1. Sign out and back in again,
2. Force refresh their token, or
3. Wait up to one hour for that token to automatically refresh by the Fireabse Auth SDK.

On then will their new token show the custom claim.

Comment: I have:
a) Forced token refresh, by logging the user again which created a new token.
b) Added admin claim for a user that hasn't logged in in over 5 hours and then logged in that user.
Still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: How do you know the claim isn't there?

Comment: I make a log in requst via  Firebase Auth REST API , using axios which returns a promise . If that promise is succesfully resolved I get back an object, which in turn has a `data` object. When I check that the data object(via console.log) it doesn't have an `admin' property

Comment: If you are referring to the axios request, because in the `data` object I receive the email and userId for that user(which are correct) , among others like token , expiresIn etc. 
If you are referring to something else please clarify

Comment: In the spirit of providing full reproduction steps, I suggest adding that code and the result so we can complete the loop.  You could also write code to call getUser and see if returns what you expect.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getuser